# How to make JavaScript write result over time (not instantly)?

Tags: javascript

I have a program, which writes a lots if results. For example, this:

```
const a = prompt();
for(let i = 1; i < a; i ++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

(not an actual code) 
So when you type a big number, there are a ton of answers waiting to be put in console. So, when it reaches some point, built-in browser compiler (Opera GX) just stops working. I need some way to write these numbers immediately after calculating, hopefully, without wasting time. How can I do that?
(just for you to know, my actual code puts results in "div" element)

Comment: *"built-in compiler just stops working"* You should elaborate on that.

Comment: What's the difference between instantly and immediately? In the title: _"How to make JavaScript write result over time (not instantly)?"_ and in the description: _"I need some way to write these numbers immediately"_

Comment: Instantly means "keeping those values to print after the program finishes". Immediately means "I calculated that number. I should put it in a console and start to calculate other one". Just like in Python (but, hopefully, much faster)

Comment: You could try recursive `setTimeout`. This will break one long-running code into many small snippets managed by the event loop. Something like `let i = 0; setTimeout(function f() { ++i; console.log(i); if (i < a) setTimeout(f, 0); }, 0);`

Comment: Have you looked into Service Workers? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Comment: @jabaa Can this code be limited by some "max recursion depth" limits, or something else? I can't understand it by myself

Comment: No, it's not really a recursive function. It pushes a new event into the event loop. Events are stored in an array-like structure.

Comment: @RickardElimää You should post an answer. That's probably the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded. This means while your loop is running, events can't be handled and the page doesn't respond. You could use "recursive" `setTimeout`. This will break one long-running code into many small snippets managed by the event loop.

```js
const a = prompt();
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const f = (() => {
  let i = 0;
  return () => {
    for (let j = 0; j < 1e9; ++j) {} // simulates long calculation 
    ++i;
    console.log(i);
    container.innerText += ' ' + i;
    if (i < a) setTimeout(f, 0);
  };
})();
setTimeout(f, 0);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

It's not a real recursive call, and it won't create a large call stack. `setTimeout(f, 0)` pushes an event into the event loop, that is almost immediately removed and handled.

I only used the closure to avoid a global counter `i`. A simpler, but less clean version is

```js
const a = prompt();
const container = document.getElementById('container');
let i = 0;
function f() {
  for (let j = 0; j < 1e9; ++j) {} // simulates long calculation 
  ++i;
  console.log(i);
  container.innerText += ' ' + i;
  if (i < a) setTimeout(f, 0);
};
setTimeout(f, 0);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Remember, that the page is still non-responsive during the loops (long calculation), but now you have many shorter loops instead of one long-running loop and events are handled between two loops.