# How to make JavaScript asynchronous so that I can accept user input?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, user-input, infinite-loop

When the webpage loads I am running this code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < count;) {
    
    ...
    
    if(condition) {
        //draw with canvas api
        ++i
    }
}
```

It's a potentially infinite while/for loop that draws some art.

If I keep the art variables reasonable, then the piece finishes and the loop exists. But sometimes it could take several minutes or potentially run forever.

The problem is, when this is happening the browser can't accept any user input. So, there's no way for the user to halt the algorithm, eg. with a button.

How can I receive user input while running this loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript write result over time (not instantly)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213368/how-to-make-javascript-write-result-over-time-not-instantly)

Comment: What is the `condition`? What are the `art variables`? We need a bit more then a loop to know what you are trying to do -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can apply the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213768/16540390 or use [Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)

Comment: @jabaa Don't you mean [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)?

Comment: @Reyno Yes, you're right.