# Correctly delaying setTimeout

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In the following function

```
function test1(n, delay) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)      
    }, delay)    
  }  
}

test1(3, 1000)
```

After 1 second, I immediately `console.log` 1, 2, and 3 simultaneously.

If I multiply `delay` by `i`,

```
function test1(n, delay) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)      
    }, i * delay)    
  }  
}

test1(3, 1000)
```

I `console.log` every `i` in my loop after 1 second. Why does this work?

Also, why does the code below

```
function test2(n, delay) {
  let promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve()    
  }, delay))
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    promise.then(console.log(i))  
  }  
}

test2(3, 1000)
```

immediately `console.log` 1, 2, and 3 simultaneously instead of waiting every second to `console.log` the next `i` value? Is there a way to `console.log` the next `i` value using promise chaining after waiting every second without using `async` and `await`?

Comment: There are multiple questions and all of them are duplicates. _"Is there a way to console.log the next i value after waiting every second without using async and await?"_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213768/16540390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why we need to multiply `i` with `delay` is by doing that you set a `timeout` with timeout 1s/2s/3s. In the example, you make the `console.log()` execute it after 1 seconds, 2 seconds and 3 seconds.....

If you doesn't multiply the `i` with delay, then all timeout you assign using `for` loop will executed after 1 (`delay`) second at the same time (you could almost ignore the execution time of `for` loop.

Another solution to loop every second is to use `setInterval`:

```js
let i = 0;
let interval;
function test2(n,delay){
 //Change millisecond to second
   delay*=1000
   interval = setInterval(function(){
       console.log(i);
       i++;
       if(i>n)
       window.clearInterval(interval)
    },delay)
   }
test2(10,1)
```