# End node.js process with a loop after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having some issues with ending a node process after an X amount of seconds.

I tried some things of this nature:

```js
setTimeout(() => { process.exit(0) }, 5000)
```

I have tried passing 1 into `.exit()`. I tried `.kill()`, and `.abort()`. I can't seem to find a solution!
I'm running a loop that is initiated after setTimeout.
The loop looks like this:

```js
let ran = 0;
while(true) {
   ran++;
   console.log(ran)
}
```

Comment: Running that in my console works for me just fine. What process are you trying to exit? How was that process created?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. `setTimeout` enqueues a new function after the last function finishes. How is the remaining script structured? Does it allow `process.exit()` to be evaluated?

Comment: I'm running an endless loop until that timer is supposed to go off and ultimately end the process. First, I create the timeout then initiate the loop. While and For loops are the same. I'm just simply running node index,js through my console.

Comment: That won't work. Running an infinite loop blocks the thread. Can you restructure it, e.g. us a recursion of `setTimeout`?

Comment: you mean place the loop inside the timeout? Would there be a way to end the process while the loop is running?

Comment: No, not place the loop inside the timeout. Replace the loop with `setTimeout`. You would need a second thread or worker, to exit/kill the process.

Comment: @jabaa I'm not sure I understand. At that point, where would I place my process.exit()?

Comment: In this answer, I describe how you can replace a loop with a `setTimeout` and allow other functions to be called between iterations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213368/how-to-make-javascript-write-result-over-time-not-instantly/70213768#70213768 This would allow to kill/exit the process after 5000, but only between iterations. Another approach is using a [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: Have a look at the event loop guide: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick - your while(true) blocks it from executing the setTimeout callback.

Comment: You cannot use a script to end an endless (synchronous) script -- because JavaScript is single-threaded, so when would the ending script get a chance to run? If your loop were asynchronous and you decided to yield control by awaiting something once in a while, then your timer callback would have a chance to execute.  The alternative is to check the time _inside_ the endless loop with Date.getTime and wait for 5 seconds to elapse from a timestamp obtained before the loop started.  But overall it's bad form to create an endless loop in JavaScript (with hopes of interrupting it externally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to replace the loop with recursive `setTimeout`:

```
let ran = 0;
function f() {
   ran++;
   console.log(ran)
   setTimeout(f, 0);
}
f();

setTimeout(() => { process.exit(0) }, 5000)
```

This allows `process.exit(0)` to be called between two iterations.